# kite-dataset option mentioning hive database

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, kite-dataset

I have to create a `movies` table in the `movielens` database instead of `default` hive database using Kite-dataset. I have already created a `movielens` database in hive manually.

So please advice what is the option I need to use with below command.

```
$ kite-dataset create movies --schema movie.avsc (-database movielens)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the `dataset` URI in this pattern,

```
dataset:hive:<namespace>/<dataset-name>
```

The `create` statement would be

```
$ kite-dataset create dataset:hive:movielens/movies --schema movie.avsc
```

Refer [Dataset URIs](http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.1.0/URIs.html).